# ASP.NET-MVC2: Why does TryUpdateModel ignore properties after the second level of the object model tree?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but it seems that anything in the object model tree 3 or more levels down, is ignored when using TryUpdateModel.

For example (simplified):

```
public virtual ActionResult SomeAction(int id, FormCollection form)
    {

        IValueProvider vpFrom = form.ToValueProvider();
        /*
        At this stage, vpForm contains:
        1)PropertyA
        2) PropertyB.SubPropertyA
        3) PropertyB.SubPropertyB.SubSubPropertyA
        */

        TryUpdateModel(someObjectModel, null, null, null, vpFrom);
        //The first two properties are applied, number (3) seems to be ignored
```

Am I missing something here?  If this is just the way it is, has anyone come up with a workaround?

Comment: Does your ModelState contain any errors after binding?

Comment: @bzlm : ModelState is valid after binding - no errors.  However, ModelState has no record of any third level properties (number 3 in the example).

Comment: I would recommend using a denormalized view model and accepting a denormalized command/parameter object back in your action parameters. You can map the command object to your domain in the service or domain layer. FormCollection = ick.

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, I probably will have to do that.  But why though?  It seems so abritrary on the part of the model binder.  Formcollection is handy for generic approaches though.

Comment: Sorry I can't answer the "why" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick project created with the following model.

```
public class TestModel {
    public TestModelA A { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelA {
    public TestModelB B { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelB {
    public TestModelC C { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelC {
    public TestModelD D { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelD {
    public TestModelE E { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelE {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my edit - which is essentially the same as yours

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form) {
    IValueProvider vpFrom = form.ToValueProvider();

    Models.TestModel t = new Models.TestModel();

    TryUpdateModel(t, null, null, null, vpFrom);

    return View(t);
}
```

This all works exactly as expected with all the models created properly. The only problem that I can see happening is that you possibly aren't passing the same property names back from the form. (by not using `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A.B.C.CName)%>` for example)

The models require parameterless constructors. But I'm sure you would have gotten an error about that - unless you're consuming the error.

So without more information about your project it will be hard to help as a basic setup produces expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is in one of your model classes. Check, please, if *PropertyB.SubPropertyB.SubSubPropertyA* is really a property but not a field. A property should have *get* and *set* accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my checklist:

1. Make sure you're getting the value back in the form request. Request["A.B.C.Name"] and etc.
2. All the required fields are on the form.
3. I had deleteOnNull issue with Linq to SQL: [How to set DeleteOnNull from designer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/69c714b9-8c73-49f3-88a9-d03b70108f68/) for future ref if you're using L2SQL.